# Can a monk knock down an enemy with a bonus action (without Open Hand Technique)?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk

Can a monk knock down an enemy with a bonus action (without Open Hand Technique) instead of the 2nd unarmed strike?
Or it needs a special archetype, or a warrior class?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and maybe visit the [help] to get some suggestion in posting questions&answer here! It is not clear to me what you mean with "knock down": do you mean reduce to 0 hp? Make it unconscious? Shove them?

Comment: @Eddymage: I'm guessing that Odin's talking about making them fall prone, since the question mentions the Open Hand monk's Open Hand Technique feature (which says, in part: "Whenever you hit a creature with one of the attacks granted by your Flurry of Blows, you can impose one of the following effects on that target: - It must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or be knocked prone. [...]"). But I agree that it'd be good to get confirmation that that's what's being asked about.

Comment: @V2Blast Yep, I thought so, after having read the game feature the OP is referring to. It seems so even from the comment to my answer down below.

Answer (score 5):

#### Unless a special feature says you can use a bonus action to shove a creature, you have to take the Attack Action.

Since the Open Hand Technique is not an option, a monk should take the Attack Action and choose the Shove special attack, as depicted in the [rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature):

> Using the Attack action, you can make a special melee attack to shove a creature, either to knock it prone or push it away from you.

If you have the Extra Attack feature, you can substitute one of the attacks with the Shove attack:

> If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

##### Other Monk options rather than Open Hand Technique.

The Monk [Way of the Four Elements](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#WayoftheFourElements) archetype has a couple of options that allow to kick prone an enemy: ***Fist of Unbroken Air*** and ***Water Whip***, but you must spend an action (and ki points) to use these features and not a bonus action.

##### If multiclassing is allowed at your table, there is an option.

The Barbarian class has an archetype, the [Path of the Totem Warrior](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheTotemWarrior), that allows to knock a creature prone using a bonus action:

> **Elk**
>
> While raging, you can use a bonus action during your move to pass through the space of a Large or smaller creature. That creature must succeed on a Strength saving throw (DC 8 + your Strength bonus + your proficiency bonus) or be knocked prone and take bludgeoning damage equal to 1d12 + your Strength modifier.
>
> **Wolf**
>
> While you’re raging, you can use a bonus action on your turn to knock a Large or smaller creature prone when you hit it with melee weapon attack.

But this requires to take **14** levels in the Barbarian class.

---

The Fighter has several archetypes that allow to shove and kick an enemy prone, but they usually activate on an hit and they may have other requirements (*e.g.* the ***Trip Attack*** of the [Battle Master](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#BattleMaster) archetype requires to spend a superiority die, the ***Ferocious Charger*** of the Cavalier archetype requires you to move at least 10ft in a straight line).

Comment: ok.and grapling work the same? After them, a 3rdlvl monk can't use an unarmed strike with a bonus action?

Comment: @OdinDodin Yes, I did not check but Grapple works as Shove, if you look at the rules.